# How to show option in windows context menu on right click only if has directory

Tags: windows, context-menu, regedit

For example if you right click on any simple folder Tortoise Git doesn't show "Git Sync" in the menu but if you go to folder that has .git folder its shows up.

How I can do that?

I only found that how I can create for any file/folder but I need for specific

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171%28VS.85%29.aspx#dynamic_behavior

Comment: @hjpotter92 This is not what I looking for, this only helps to show the option when I right click on file that contains that word. I want to show the option when I right click on folder that contains that file not on the file itself

Answer (score 1):

To do what you need, it is neccesary to create a [Explorer extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067(v=vs.85).aspx). But you can achieve almost the same adding a registry key. In this last case, option will be shown always for all folders.

Here you have the [step by step instructions to add the registry key](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/add-the-command-prompt-to-the-windows-explorer-right-click-menu/).